# Integer valued to 0 not present in output using GRPCv3

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I am using GRPCv3 on node.js

I have a .proto file with the following message:

```
message ProductAvailabilityWithRatesResponse {
    // How many slots are available for this day/time. Mandatory.
    int32 capacity = 1;
    // Date for when this product is available. Mandatory.
    Date date = 2;
    // When does this event start? Unset if this product does not support times.
    Time time = 3;
    // When does a pickup for this product start? Unset if this product does not support times or pickups.
    Time pickupTime = 4;
    // Rates with prices. Mandatory (should at least have one entry).
    repeated RateWithPrice rates = 5;
}
```

on the server using console.log i see this output:

```
{ capacity: 1,
  date: { year: 2019, month: 7, day: 1 },
  rates: [ { rateId: 1, pricePerPerson: [Object] } ],
  time: { hour: 9, minute: 0 } }
```

and on a client using node.js too:

```
{ rates:
   [ { rateId: '1',
       pricePerPerson: [Object],
       pricingOptions: 'pricePerPerson' } ],
  capacity: 0,
  date: { year: 2019, month: 7, day: 1 },
  time: { hour: 9, minute: 0 },
  pickupTime: null }
```

but another person using a java client tells me that he sees:

```
2019-06-26 10:59:39,442  ← getProductAvailability::grpc response {date { year: 2019 month: 7 day: 1 } time { hour: 9 } rates { rateId: "1" pricePerPerson { pricingCategoryWithPrice { pricingCategoryId: "30" price { currency: "EUR" amount: "145" } } pricingCategoryWithPrice { pricingCategoryId: "31" price { currency: "EUR" amount: "150" } } } }}
```

where capacity is not set. 
If it's value is 1 and not 0, everything works well everywhere. 
Is it possible?
How can i force the server to output the value?
I already tried using capacity = parseInt(capacity)

Comment: What is gRPCv3? Also, what exactly is the source of these objects you are printing out?

Comment: The node.js library is: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node as in: https://grpc.io/grpc/node/

The server is started with:
`
function main() {
var server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(hello_proto.PluginApi.service, {
GetProductAvailability:GetProductAvailability, 
});
}
`

and the server response is like this:

`
function GetProductAvailability(call) {
  pr = {};
  pr.capacity = result[index].numero;
  pr.capacity = parseInt(pr.capacity + 0);
  pr.date = {year: d.getFullYear(), month: (d.getMonth()+1), day:d.getDate()};
  ....
  call.write(pr);
  call.end();
}
`

Comment: OK, I know what the Node gRPC library is, but there is no version 3 of that library. Can you add that code to the question itself, and also include the `console.log` lines that are outputting the output we are looking at?